# Exception handling?

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;                          

class ExceptionHandling
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        StreamReader streamReader = null;   
        try
        {
        streamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\Sample Files\\Data.txt");      
        Console.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadToEnd());                              
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException ex)                                         
        {       
            Console.WriteLine("Please check if the file {0} exists",ex.FileName); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {   
            if (streamReader !=null)                
            {
            streamReader.Close();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("FInally Block");   
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are as follow:

1) In `StreamReader streamReader = null;`  why is streamReader assigned to null?

2) `streamReader = new StreamReader`  I just want to clarify this. Is streamReader reference variable pointing to StreamReader object?

3) If exception occurs in `streamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\Sample Files\\Data.txt");`, does streamReader still get open?

4) Since we wrote `StreamReader streamReader = null;`  isn't streamReader always null and therefore it's impossible to close in the Finally block?

5)I'm not sure how `FileNotFoundException ex` and `Exception ex` work. Isn't ex object reference variable and doesn't it only work once we assign them to the object like `Exception ex = new Exception`?

Comment: Too many questions. Reading the documentation and a good beginning C# book is where you should start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This statement means that later if you want to check that the streamReader was opened correctly you can do `streamReader == null`
2. This instantiates a new instance of the streamReader object from a path.
3. No the streamReader will not open and the exception will be thrown.
4. In the finally block this will be run if an exception occurs and also if one doesn't. Therefore it is important to dispose of any allocated system resources.
5. FileNotFound is thrown on opening a streamReader however the exception ex is the general case for any other exception.

Some general info on the streamReader it is a class which inherits from a System.IO.Stream object (Has similar properties to). It allocates system resources on instantiation and declares itself as reading a certain stream (a filestream in this case). Therefore if you instantiate a streamReader you NEED to close it so that other applications can access the resource.

The reason that it stops other applications from reading that resource is to prevent multi threading issues from occurring, i.e. one application reads a document, the programmer assumes that the document is unchanging between when their program opens the document and when they close it. If another program comes along and changes some text insde the file, the original program could crash and result in a BSOD.

Comment: Like you said, if the streamReader will not open and the exception will be thrown why do we have to close it in the finally block?

Comment: If an exception isn't thrown you still need to dispose of the streamReader

Comment: Cjen 1 thank you very much. I've been studying with tutorials so there wasn't any information on disposing streamReader and resources etc. Could you tell me what they are.

Answer (score 2):

1. That simply initializes the `streamReader` variable to `null`. If you didn't initialize the value, you'd get compiler errors about using an uninitialized variable in the `fianally` block.
2. Yes.
3. No. But there's a chance that the `StreamReader` constructor will succeed but the call to `streamReader.ReadToEnd()` will throw an Exception. In that case, you'll have an open `streamReader`.
4. No, see the above answer.
5. The different `catch` blocks allow you to handle different types of errors. Only one `catch` block will handle any given Exception. C# will figure out the most specific Exception that you handle and ensure that you enter that block. The actual instance of the Exception (`ex`) will be constructed and passed to the block by the Framework. You don't need to do anything explicit.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. It was really helpful but in your answer 3, could explain when  the StreamReader constructor will succeed but the call to streamReader.ReadToEnd() will throw an Exception?

Comment: @jelly - If you look at the documentation for the method, there's an "Exceptions" section that tells you exactly which Exceptions a method might throw and what the cause would be:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.110).aspx